# Getting a value from a named range in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to retrieve a value from named range. Imagine a named range that has X columns and Y rows. I want to return a value, e.g., from column 2, row 3. The issue I experience is that if I write the code and run it, Excel throws an error. If I write the code into the watch window, it returns fine. See below

```
...
Dim NamedRange As Variant: NamedRange = Range(NamedRangeName)
...
Dim ReturnValue As Object
Set ReturnValue = NamedRange(RowIndex, ColumnToRetrieveIndex) 'Throws Run-time error 424. Object required
```

If I write
NamedRange(RowIndex, ColumnToRetrieveIndex)
into the watch window, I can see the correct value of the cell.

I don't know VB much so I guess it's just some kind of syntax error how I want to pass it into the ReturnValue but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use this

```
ThisWorkbook.Names("myNamedRange").RefersToRange(1,1)
```

To get the value from the first cell in the named range "myNamedRange"

With `ThisWorkbook.Names` you can access all named ranges of all the sheets within the current workbook.
With `RefersToRange` you get a reference to the actual range.

Comment: This was useful but if you have scoped you name to a particular worksheet in Names Manager you may need to consider something like `ActiveSheet.Names`.

Answer (score 5):

This looks like a good place to put a handy note (as it's a top search result):
If you name a cell "TopLeft", then `Sheets(1).Range("TopLeft").Value`  gets the contents, and `Sheets(1).Range("TopLeft").Offset(2,3).Value` gets the value from 2 down, 3 across from there.