# How to populate a drop down list by VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba

The Target.Offset cell in the excel worksheet is a dynamic data validation drop down list (i.e. dependent on another drop down list). I want it to be populated with the first, or maybe the second item of its list, instead of Null.

Any idea of a simple code?

```
     Target.Offset(0, 1).MergeArea.Value = Null
```

Comment: How about a "null" list, when the 1st dropdown is blank?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If you mean a list with the name "null", it cannot be done, since the list name is dependent on the value of the previous list.

Comment: I was thinking more of `if target="" then: your data list =something else`

Comment: Thank you, I was managed to find a solution. Pls see my own answer to the post.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution in this forum. It should be:

```
 = ThisWorkbook.Names("myNamedRange").RefersToRange(1,1)
```

To get the value from the first cell in the named range "myNamedRange"

link to the origin post: 
[Getting a value from a named range in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26242960/getting-a-value-from-a-named-range-in-vba)

Thank you!

Comment: Good for you, nice find :) Does it always grab the first non-null value like you wanted?

Comment: It grabs the first row in the list even if it's a null. So If you want the second item which is not null, you should change it to (2,1).

Answer (score 1):

just wanted to add a little bit to the answer you found so that you know how to grab the first non-blank value from that named range.

```
Sub FirstFilledInNamedRange()

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Names("myNamedRange").RefersToRange

    Dim val As String
    val = rng.Find(What:="*", After:=rng(rng.rows.count, rng.Columns.count)).Value2

    MsgBox val

End Sub
```