# Code runs on a different column which is incorrect

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code which runs perfectly on a targeted column. The problem though is when someone inserts a new column, the code does not recognize that the column has shifted as a result of the inserted column.

when the code runs, it then runs on the wrong column.

can someone please help me with how to ensure that the code is running on the desired column even if there is a new column inserted.

Please see below code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Oldvalue As String
    Dim Newvalue As String

    On Error GoTo Exitsub

    If Target.Column = 24 And Target.Row > 4 And Target.Row < 500 Then
        If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
        GoTo Exitsub
        Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Newvalue = Target.Value
            Application.Undo
            Oldvalue = Target.Value
            If Oldvalue = "" Then
                Target.Value = Newvalue
            Else
                Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
            End If
        End If
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

Exitsub:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

That's the code that runs perfectly but on the wrong column if a new column has been inserted.

Comment: You need some way of defining the target column.

Comment: Define a named range for your column, and then refer to that column in your `Worksheet_Change` event sub. Excel will keep track of it for you.

Comment: Named Ranges: https://exceljet.net/named-ranges

Get a value from a Named Range: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26242960/getting-a-value-from-a-named-range-in-vba